# Permission denied with Perl Storable

Tags: perl, permissions, permission-denied, storable

I am trying to persist data across a perl CGI application (when a submit button is clicked). But the following code:

```
use Storable;
my %hash = ('1'=>'a','2'=>'b','3'=>'c');
store \%hash, 'handle';
```

returns:

```
Error executing run mode 'Admin Page': can't create handle: Permission denied at Main.pm line 76
```

How do I give the script permission to save the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the user the web server runs as does not have permissions to write to the directory. As a test, try `store \%hash, '/tmp/handle';`, and if that works, you'll need to get directory permissions sorted where you want to save the data.

Comment: Seems to be the issue. Will get my network admin to check it out! Thanks